# Nashorn Javascript debugging with CompiledScript?

Tags: nashorn

It seems mandatory to use the `load(filename)` [Nashorn extension](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Extensionproperties,functionsinglobalobject) when wanting to be able to debug both Java and Javascript in an IDE, see e.g. [Debugging Nashorn JavaScript with Intellij](http://davidbuccola.blogspot.de/2015/02/debugging-nashorn-javascript-with.html)

Unfortunately, this prohibits the use of `CompiledScript`, as the above returns a `ScriptObjectMirror` object, and at least no `compile(filename)` Nashorn extension is documented.

One of the `CompiledScript` functionalities being lost here is e.g. `CompiledScript.eval(ScriptContext context)`. I couldn't find a way of achieving the same using `ScriptObjectMirror`. Also, `load(filename)` will immediately execute the script, which may not be wanted.

Comment: See also https://github.com/aperto/sourceurl-resourcefilter for a Maven Resource Filter that will add `//@ sourceURL=` annotations automatically to JS source files. This will result in file names being displayed in Nashorn JS stackframes in the Netbeans debugger, even when `load()` is not used, e.g. with `CompiledScript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug any Nashorn/JavaScript with IDEs using this ->

https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/remote_debugging_of_nashorn_scripts

- introduce "debugger" statement in your script
- Use your IDE to insert breakpoint in jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.DEBUGGER method
- start "Debug" in your IDE

See also for IntelliJ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38513981/3189360

With the recent NetBeans builds, the second part is not needed. NetBeans will automatically break into any "debugger" statement.

See https://twitter.com/sundararajan_a/status/773375676103602178

Comment: Thx, but setting a break point wasn't my problem, as I can already put it in the Java exception that is being thrown in my case.
What I am looking for is stack frames corresponding to .js source lines, and .js source being shown when selecting those stack frames. Otherwise I have no clue what variables I am looking at :)

Comment: Well, NetBeans shows source (even when "eval"ed from a String) when that breakpoint hits. And stack frames in stack traces have to use artificial name - as there is no name associated by user. Not much can be done there. But, Nashorn implement @sourceURL / #sourceURL directives. ( https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8032068 ). That is useful to associate a readable name for eval'ed sources.

Comment: NetBeans is the next thing I'll try, as [IDEA has a bug when debugging maven dependencies](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162333). Do you per chance know whether NetBeans will show sources also on CompiledScript invocations, i.e. without using `load()`?

Comment: OK NetBeans debugging works perfect, also on `CompiledScript` (as long as `// @ sourceURL =...` annotation is present). Thx!