# Debugging Javascript stored in a variable executed by Nashorn and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, java, debugging, intellij-idea, nashorn

I have loaded my Javascript from database (for example) into a String object and while I can execute it, I wonder how can I debug it in IntelliJ IDEA!?

So far I've read the following pages on the topic:

1. [Debugger for JDK8’s Nashorn JavaScript in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/debugger-for-jdk8s-nashorn-javascript-in-intellij-idea-13-1/)
2. [Debug dynamically loaded JavaScript code with IntelliJ and the Nashorn engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513138/debug-dynamically-loaded-javascript-code-with-intellij-and-the-nashorn-engine)
3. [Remote debugging of nashorn scripts with NetBeans IDE using "debugger" statements](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/remote_debugging_of_nashorn_scripts)

and while they are insightful, but none of them actually help. The second link has a good idea on how to set a breakpoint in Javascript using `debugger;` and setting a method breakpoint on:

- **class:** jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime
- **method:** DEBUGGER

This way, the execution process actually stops on the line but it stops in a Java file (that belongs to the mentioned class) and from there, there's no way you can get to Javascript.

So is there any way I can debug an in memory Javascript?

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "step out" from that Java method? that should land in the JavaScript code's debugger statement..

Comment: No, the step out takes you to the java code and at least I could not find my way to the Javascript from there. But I did find another way to make it happen in IntelliJ IDEA and I'll share it the first chance I'll get even though it's not that elegant since it requires saving the JS code on a temporary file.